# Strange Java ArrayList behavior

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am working on my beginners project for learning java. 
The project is to a add, list and delete person. like

type 1 to add a person 
type 2 to list all person 
type 3 to delete a person.

I am using ArrayList collections to work on this project.

The first question is is using the collections is a good aproach? 
if yes i am declaring the ArrayList globally but while iterating it I can see it's not storing any data.

my code is as follows.

```
import java.util.*;  

public class OperationClass implements OperationInterface {  
    String id;  
    String fname;  
    String lname;  
    ArrayList<String> Person=new ArrayList<String>();  

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        new OperationClass().operation();  
    }  

    public static void operation() {  
        int a;  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Adding new Record");  
        System.out.println("Enter 2 to see List of Records");  
        System.out.println("Enter 3 to Delete a record");  
        System.out.println("Enter 4 to Exit!!");  

        a = in.nextInt();  

        if (a == 1) {  
            new OperationClass().addPerson();  
        } if (a == 2) {  
            new OperationClass().listPerson();  
        } if (a == 3) {  
            new OperationClass().deletePerson();  
        } if (a == 4) {  
            System.out.println("Thanks for using the program");  
        }  
    }  

    /** 
     * adds a new Person and stores in the collection 
     */  
    @Override  
    public void addPerson() {  


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
new OperationClass().operation();  
        System.out.println("Enter a the id");  
        id = in.next();  

        System.out.println("Enter a the First Name");  
        fname = in.next();  

        System.out.println("Enter a the Last Name");  
        lname = in.next();  


        Person.add(id);  
        Person.add(fname);  
        Person.add(lname);  



        new OperationClass().operation();  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void listPerson() {  
        Iterator itr=Person.iterator();  
        while(itr.hasNext()){  
            System.out.println(itr.next());  
        }  
     new OperationClass().operation();  

    }  

    @Override  
    public void deletePerson() {  
        System.out.println("Delete under construction");  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void quit() {  

    }  
}
```

**first output is**

Enter 1 for Adding new Record.

Enter 2 to see List of Records.

Enter 3 to Delete a record .

Enter 4 to Exit!!

**while entering 1 its coming like this**

Enter 1 for Adding new Record

Enter 2 to see List of Records

Enter 3 to Delete a record

Enter 4 to Exit!!

1

Enter a the id

1

Enter a the First Name

Indranil

Enter a the Last Name

Sinha

**Then after hitting enter again the first four options are coming and after going to 2 its not showing anything.**

Enter 1 for Adding new Record

Enter 2 to see List of Records

Enter 3 to Delete a record

Enter 4 to Exit!!

1

Enter a the id

1

Enter a the First Name

asdasd

Enter a the Last Name

dsffdgdfg

Enter 1 for Adding new Record

Enter 2 to see List of Records

Enter 3 to Delete a record

Enter 4 to Exit!!

2

Enter 1 for Adding new Record

Enter 2 to see List of Records

Enter 3 to Delete a record

Enter 4 to Exit!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your `ArrayList` as an `instance variable`.

In simplest words it means for `a new object a new ArrayList will be cretaed`.

Now while calling methods you are doing, `new OperationClass().addPerson();`

In all these statements `new OperationClass();` creates a new object and hence creates a new `ArrayList`.

Therefore in the last you don't get anything in one list.

I would suggest the following:

1. As your `public static void operation()` method is static, so you don't need to create an object to call it. You can call it directly by class name.

Therefore `new OperationClass().operation();` can be replaced by `OperationClass.operation();`. However it won't solve your problem.

### Solutions

2. What you need to do is have one common object of `OperationClass` and store it in some reference variable then use this only one object to call your other methods i.e. Don't call `new OperationClass()` again and again.
3. The alternate which can work with your same code will be declare your `ArrayList` to be static i.e. `static ArrayList<String> Person=new ArrayList<String>();`.

By doing this it will be common for all the objects and you will be adding data to a single common `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks a lot....for this wonderful answer. It not only solved my problem but taught me new lessons.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new `OperationClass` object every time you enter a number:

```
if (a == 1) {  
    new OperationClass().addPerson(); //Creating a new object
} if (a == 2) {  
    new OperationClass().listPerson(); //Creating a new object
} if (a == 3) {  
    new OperationClass().deletePerson(); //Creating a new object
} if (a == 4) {  
    System.out.println("Thanks for using the program");  
}
```

Try calling the methods on the object you already have:

```
if (a == 1) {  
    addPerson();  
} if (a == 2) {  
    listPerson();  
} if (a == 3) {  
    deletePerson();  
} if (a == 4) {  
    System.out.println("Thanks for using the program");  
}
```

This will call the methods on the object you create in your `main()`.

### edit:

As pointed out, this will not quite work since your `operation()` method is static. I would suggest to either make this method non-static (and therefore an instance method):

```
public void operation() { 
    //Your operation() code
}
```

or move `operation()`s code to a constructor of `OperationClass` alltogether so that it's code is ran right when you create an object of that class:

```
public OperationClass() {
    //Your operation() code
}
```

Comment: `public static void operation()` The `operation()` method is declared to be static therefore, you won't be able to call the `instance methods` from there directly like you say, `addPerson()`. OP will need an object to do so.

Comment: or the alternate will be to make the `operation()` method to be instance method. i.e. `public void operation()`

Answer (score 2):

You have `new OperationClass().operation()/add/list...;` almost everywhere, you should know that, when you `new ...` a new instance was created, thus, with an empty `ArrayList<String> Person` List.

You may want to use the same instance, instead of creating a new one every time.

Answer (score 2):

here is working and modified code for you:

```
import java.util.*;  

public class OperationClass implements OperationInterface {  
    String id;  
    String fname;  
    String lname;  
    static ArrayList<String> Person=new ArrayList<String>();  

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        new OperationClass().operation();  
    }  

    public static void operation() {  
        int a;  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Adding new Record");  
        System.out.println("Enter 2 to see List of Records");  
        System.out.println("Enter 3 to Delete a record");  
        System.out.println("Enter 4 to Exit!!");  

        a = in.nextInt();  

        if (a == 1) {  
            new OperationClass().addPerson();  
        } if (a == 2) {  
            new OperationClass().listPerson();  
        } if (a == 3) {  
            new OperationClass().deletePerson();  
        } if (a == 4) {  
            System.out.println("Thanks for using the program");  
        }  
    }  

    /** 
     * adds a new Person and stores in the collection 
     */  
    @Override  
    public void addPerson() {  


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Enter a the id");  
        id = in.next();  

        System.out.println("Enter a the First Name");  
        fname = in.next();  

        System.out.println("Enter a the Last Name");  
        lname = in.next();  


        Person.add(id);  
        Person.add(fname);  
        Person.add(lname);  



        new OperationClass().operation();  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void listPerson() {  
        Iterator itr=Person.iterator();  
        while(itr.hasNext()){  
            System.out.println(itr.next());  
        }  
     new OperationClass().operation();  

    }  

    @Override  
    public void deletePerson() {  
        System.out.println("Delete under construction");  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void quit() {  

    }  
}
```